# Iterative Models and Stateless Environments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iteration

I have an iterative simulation model that does X per timestep. What's the best way to simulate that iterative model in a stateless environment like ASP.NET?

Simulation data is in the 10 to 15 MB range.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx), or if using WebForms, you can also use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Or just design for statelessness.  Serve each "timestep" with *all* of the information necessary to advance to the next state.  Instead of thinking of the problem as one of managing state, think of it as a large form that gets passed between multiple parties and is gradually filled in by each one.